# What is the title of sci-fi novel where lizards became more advanced than humans?

Tags: story-identification

I've read some sci-fi novel long ago where lizards during natural selection became more advanced than humans. Also, as some clue, in that book's world transport was mostly biological - I remember giant fishes used as transport. Can't remember its title.

Comment: And there was me hoping it was a novelisation of the [Super Mario Bros. movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Mario_Bros._(film)).

Comment: [...] **Than** humans?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"West of Eden" by Harry Harrison.

The dinosaur race is known as the Yilanè. The human-like race, the Tanu, had evolved from new world monkeys instead of apes.

The story continues in two sequels, *Winter in Eden* and *Return to Eden*.

[Wikipedia notes:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_of_Eden)

> The Yilanè, having had millions of years of civilization, have a very
>   advanced society primarily based on a mastery of the biological
>   sciences, especially genetic engineering, so much so that almost every
>   tool and artifact they use is a modified lifeform. Their boats were
>   originally squids, their submarines are enhanced ichthyosaurs (here
>   called uruketos), while their guns are modified monitor lizards which
>   eject projectiles using pressurised gas.

[image]